# Authorize.net CIM profile edit CC

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

Authorize.net CIM allows to edit profile with new Credit card, expiry date and CVV information.

What in case if customer use the profile for an order and the amount is authorize with that profile with one credit card and before the amount is captured, the customer edits the same profile with new credit card info.

What in case if the customer place an order with one profile and before the amount got captured  if cusomter delete the profile.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the order is placed using their CIM profile all of the information associated with their profile *at that time* is what will be used for that payment. The edits they made after placing the order will only affect future payments with CIM. The same applies to deleting a profile.

Answer (score 1):

From what I observed and guesses, when a customer uses his current profile information for a transaction, the real card information is used (obviously Auth.net profile IDs mean nothing outside the gateway) and changing customer profile information after the transaction shouldn't affect.